# How to connect small format desktop Dell XPS to large GTX1050Ti gpu

Tags: gpu, dell-xps, animation, blender

I have a small format desktop Dell XPS 7760-7213 7th Gen Intel Core i7 512 GB of SSD 16GB RAM and just got a good deal on a GTX1050Ti 4G D5 128bit HDMI DVI VGA DVI vid card. But it's way too big for the computer case. Anybody have advice on how to turn it into an exterior gpu? I'm told they used laptop components for the XPS, so I'm guessing there is a way to do it. Trying to put together a system to run Blender and do animation. Thanx.